# how to use jmeter JSR223 PreProcessor for reading each line from csv file

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

My requirement is to send (all the files bodies at once) the multiple JSON body to the API using POST method from JMeter.

1. I have a CSV file with all the file path in json_test_plan.csv file. And in each of the four files I have the JSON body. I used

In each line, I have mentioned a file path which contains the JSON body.

```
D:\jmeter_tests\plan1.json
D:\jmeter_tests\plan2.json
D:\jmeter_tests\plan3.json
D:\jmeter_tests\plan4.json
```

2. created a HTTP Request sampler with the Body data as mentioned below:
   `{__FileToString(${JSON},,)}`
3. Added JSR223 PreProcessor as a child of the HTTP Request sampler which I use for sending the JSON input

Put the following code into Script area

```
new File("D:/jmeter_tests/json_test_plan.csv").readLines().each { line ->
def builder = new StringBuilder()
    builder.append(new File(line).text).append(System.getProperty('line.separator'))
    sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', builder.toString(), '')
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
    }
```

3. Added a http header manager, added content-type and application/json as values for Name and Value field respectively
4. Added a CSV Dataset Config mentioning the CSV data source "D:/jmeter_tests/json_test_plan.csv"

Now the issue is, each time i run a jmeter test, the above just reads the last line(row) from CSV file "D:\jmeter_tests\plan4.json" and gives the required output. think there is some indexing issue in the code. Could someone pls help me to rea each row/line from the CSV and process.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you're calling `sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()` for each file. Just remove it and your code should start working more or less okayish.

You can also think about enhancing it to use [Arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/config/Arguments.html) class

```
def data = new org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments()

def builder = new StringBuilder()
new File("D:/jmeter_tests/json_test_plan.csv").readLines().each { line ->
    builder.append(new File(line).text).append(System.getProperty('line.separator'))
}

def body = new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument('', builder.toString(), '', false)
body.setAlwaysEncoded(false)
data.addArgument(body)
sampler.setArguments(data)
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Even after i remove "sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()" the result is not expected as desired. Still it is not reading each row/line from the CSV and process.